# jquery indexOf not finding the names i am trying to block

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok so i have an input and am trying to make it so that when a specific name is inputted, it gives an alert and e.off()'s. I do not know why this code wont work. the code is in a function but that is ok, I am just having problems here Thank You. the html input does have an id of #nameInput so we are ok there too.

```
var name = $('#nameInput').val();
      var names = ["john","jon","johnn"];
      var a = names.indexOf("john","jon","johnn") > -1;

      if (name == a) {
        alert('That is the Bosses name silly!');
        e.off();
      }
```

Comment: What is the event to which you are hooking this code into? For example, does this code run on the "keydown" event? That might matter. For example, I think that the "change" event does not trigger until you leave focus, so that might be throwing you off.

Comment: `a` is the result of a `>` comparison, so a boolean value, either `true` or `false` – but you are comparing it with a string value in `name`.

Comment: What exactly is it that you expected that call to `.indexOf()` to do? You pass it the same list of strings that's in the array. What do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = $('#nameInput').val();
var names = ["john","jon","johnn"];

var bad_name = false;
for(var k in names) {
  var this_name = names[k];
  if( name.indexOf(this_name) > -1 ) {
    bad_name = true;
    break;
  }  
}

if(bad_name) {
  alert('That is the Bosses name silly!');
  e.off();
}
```

---

`.indexOf` was used incorrectly. The object it is called on should be the `name` string, not the list of names, and it only takes one parameter, so you have to do multiple checks.

Also, the `a` value would have been a boolean, so you directly check its value, not compare it to `name`

Comment: Yess thank you. This makes perfect sense. Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 3):

The `.indexOf()` function is not a jQuery thing; it's part of (modern) standard JavaScript. It takes one argument and one optional argument. The first is the thing to search for, and the second optional argument is the starting position for the search (default being index 0).

The function returns a number, as your code seems to expect. However, you then compare the name in the input field to the `true`/`false` returned from the comparison following your (incorrect) call to `.indexOf()`, so it's not surprising that it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Remember that you can use `~` to convert the result of `.indexOf()` into a truthy value. When there isn't a match, it returns -1. Using `~` will turn it into 0. If the result is something else, it is turned to it's negative oposite.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that's definitely true, but I don't think the OP has reached a point in his or her JavaScript career to start thinking about that as an option.

Comment: You are right. He is comparing `true` with a string. I guess your poing is very valid.

Answer (score 0):

If all this is in a function, consider having another function outside of it so that you can reuse it later if needed.  You need to iterate through the array of names matching your string against the array's items.  There are many many ways to do it, but here's an easy one.

```js
function isName(inputName, namesArray) {
  var nameFound = false;  //  Returns false if there's no match

  namesArray.forEach(function(name) {  // For each name in namesArray
    if (inputName === name) {
      nameFound = true;
    }
  });

  return nameFound;
}

console.log(isName('john', ['john', 'jon', 'johnn']));
console.log(isName('nobody', ['john', 'jon', 'johnn']));

// You can then have your if statement
if(isName(name, names)) {
    alert('That is the Bosses name silly!');
    e.off();
}
```